# Kryptonite iOS automate enter PIN

Tags: git

Kryptonite has the ability to read my PIN from my phone, but recently after I push to GitHub there is a prompt:

> Enter PIN for 'Kryptonite iOS':

All I have to do is press enter, but this is an extra step that didn't use to exist.

How can I get rid of this, so it just automatically reads my PIN from my phone? Pressing enter doesn't add any security and the few times I pushed to GitHub and then realized 5 minutes later I never pressed enter is pretty aggravating. FYI, I'm not using Bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was missing. Running `kr codesign` in terminal gives instructions to add a GPG to GitHub for code signing.

Solution for the SAM prompt: https://github.com/kryptco/kr/issues/307

> I believe you might be missing the IdentityAgent setting?
>
> ```
>   IdentityAgent ~/.kr/krd-agent.sock
> ```